Error in Creating User Defined package in Java
I am new to Java and recently learnt about creating user defined packages to be later imported and used in projects . I created my own package but when I entered package at the top of my file , it started showing errors 
I also tried to change my directory name as I thought the name of my folder could have been violating naming convention of identifiers in Java.

You could be unable to find a location for the imported package to cause this issue. If you are creating a Java package in a Java project and importing it. Then you need to pay attention to the path of the package, and the path when importing the package to be canonical.  Be attention this:

You need to create a package directory under src/main/java in the project. Something like this:src/main/java/com/example/mypackage.

Write the Java class in mypackage, but then write package com.example.mypackage; at the top of the file.
Import custom packages in other Java files, it should be noted that the import package import com.example.mypackage.MyClass;.

